# Datepicker date format issue

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I am trying to select a date from DatePicker. It works properly often but when i select future date, the picker sets itself to current date(as per my code of maxdate). In this date shows current date in label but at backend object it is actually 1 day minus of current date. e.g After auto set of picker to current date, it displays in label 09-Apr-2015 but in my object(nsdate) which is want to Post to server api, it shows 2015-04-08 18:30:00 +0000. Thus my object send 8 apr to the server. Kindly reply if someone has faced this problem.

Comment: Paste your code here!

Comment: You need to show code and give test details. What time zone is each piece of test data logged in? This question doesn't have enough information.

Comment: -(void)updateDateLabel
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    self.lblDOB.text = [formatter stringFromDate:dateOfBirth];
      NSLog(@"label date %@" , self.lblDOB.text);
    
    [[RKValueTransformer defaultValueTransformer] insertValueTransformer:formatter atIndex:0];
    
    self.user.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    NSLog(@"Local Object date %@", dateOfBirth);

}

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem. The date picker is giving you correct time but only in the other time zone (Appears GMT+5:30)

When you are sending the date in your API, convert it to NSString using NSDateFormatter of the default time-zone or time-zone of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing is wrong with your GMT settings.

try this code to fix:

```
[yourdataobject dateByAddingTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]];
```

This will automatically fix your date in whatever zone your app is running in.